# Can be p-value be defined as overlap of surface areas of two comparable distributions?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

P-value shows the probability of null hypothesis.

- Can we also say that if P = 0.5, then half of the surface areas of
  two comparable distributions overlap?
- And statistical significance, e.g. P < 0.05, means that the overlap of the surface areas of two comparable distributions is under 5%?

Comment: You’ve gone awry in your first sentence. The p-value is the probability of getting the observed test statistic or a more extreme test statistic, if the null hypothesis is true. This is a subtle but real difference from what you wrote, and understanding the difference is important to working in statistics.

Comment: Thank you for noting this! "if the null hypothesis is true" - does it mean that we have to excluded type I and II error? Could you please explain this part a bit more: "the observed test statistic or a more extreme test statistic"? Using a simple example would be helpful: e.g. control group mean weight 50 kg, experiment group weight 55 kg, P = 0.3.

Comment: Look at JBStatistics videos on YouTube for an explanation of the p-value. (His videos are good in general.)